# Prorammatically making a UIView height wrap its content?

Tags: c#, ios, swift, xamarin.ios

I'm creating a card and would like its height to auto adjust upon its content. I'm using Auto Layout and each element inside the card is constrained with the previous one going down.

- The header is a UIStackView.
- The gauge is a third party control.
- There are up to 5 groups of 3 UILabels.
- Finally there is a UIButton.

[image]

I'm not sure I can put a constraint between the button and its parent.

Something similar to [WrapContent on Android](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewGroup.LayoutParams#WRAP_CONTENT) would be nice.

The code for the CarView is [here](https://alexdunn.org/2018/03/29/xamarin-tip-ios-cardview/).

May be I could override IntrinsicContentSize property and return the actual size of all children's?

I've tried to add this code:

```
public override CGSize IntrinsicContentSize
{
    get
    {
        nfloat finalHeight = 0;
        foreach (UIView uIView in base.Subviews)
        {
            finalHeight += uIView.Frame.Height;
        }
        return new CGSize(this.Frame.Width, finalHeight);
    }
}
```

It is actually called very early and I have no Subview yet.

The card is created like this (Right now the card height size is fixed):

```
CardView qolCard = new CardView();
View.AddSubview(qolCard);
qolCard.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
qolCard.CornerRadius = 5f;
qolCard.ShadowOffsetHeight = 0;
qolCard.ShadowOffsetWidth = 0;
qolCard.BackgroundColor = UIColor.White;
qolCard.Anchor(leading: View.LeadingAnchor, trailing: View.TrailingAnchor, top: View.SafeAreaLayoutGuide.TopAnchor, size: new CGSize(0f, 400f), padding: new UIEdgeInsets(10f, 10f, 10f, 10f));
```

The Anchor helper method is the following:

```
internal static void Anchor(this UIView uIView, NSLayoutYAxisAnchor top = null, NSLayoutXAxisAnchor leading = null, NSLayoutYAxisAnchor bottom = null, NSLayoutXAxisAnchor trailing = null, UIEdgeInsets padding = default, CGSize size = default)
{
    uIView.TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;
    if (top != null)
    {
        uIView.TopAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(top, padding.Top).Active = true;
    }

    if (leading != null)
    {
        uIView.LeadingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(leading, padding.Left).Active = true;
    }

    if (bottom != null)
    {
        uIView.BottomAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(bottom, -padding.Bottom).Active = true;
    }

    if (trailing != null)
    {
        uIView.TrailingAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(trailing, -padding.Right).Active = true;
    }

    if (size.Width != 0)
    {
        uIView.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(size.Width).Active = true;
    }

    if (size.Height != 0)
    {
        uIView.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(size.Height).Active = true;
    }
}
```

Any help appreciated.

---

EDIT : With these simple modifications according to Jack Hua:

```
    qolCard.Anchor(leading: View.LeadingAnchor, trailing: View.TrailingAnchor, top: View.SafeAreaLayoutGuide.TopAnchor, bottom: rateButton.BottomAnchor, padding: new UIEdgeInsets(10f, 10f, 10f, 10f));
```

This gives me the following result which is not perfect, but close to what I want:

[image]

I'm surprised I could anchor a parent view to a child view. Or could I?

Comment: The easiest way is to embed everything in a vertical stack view. No need to override `intrinsicContentSize` that way.

Comment: I'm concerned about all the Text lines layout which aren't UIStackView yet. I like the idea though.

Comment: You can set constraints between the button and the UIView to fix the button at the bottom position.

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I tried what you suggested, see edit part of my question.

Comment: Then set constraints between the button and the cardView, make the bottom of cardView with a fixed space with the top of button.